# First Time Hibernate - Getting an error on runtime

Tags: hibernate

This is my code:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.configure("/com/azienda/progettoCorso/Hibernate/mode/hbm
        /hibernate.cfg.xml");                 
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction trans = session.beginTransaction();
    //ISTRUZIONI SQL
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Aula.class);
    List<Aula> list = criteria.list();
    trans.commit();
    session.getSessionFactory().close();
  }
}
```

I get this error on runtime and i dont know how to solve it. Can you help me?

```
nov 02, 2017 4:03:40 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.2.Final}
nov 02, 2017 4:03:40 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
nov 02, 2017 4:03:40 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE com/azienda/progettoCorso/Hibernate/model/hbm/hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:259)
    at com.azienda.progettoCorso.Hibernate.model.Test.main(Test.java:14)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:241)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:477)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:656)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:599)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:122)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.safeLoadClass(ContextFinder.java:594)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:239)
    ... 9 more
```

This is my configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Corso</property>
        <property name="connection.username">consoft</property>
        <property name="connection.password">consoft</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>  

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current session context class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping resource="com/azienda/progettoCorso/Hibernate/model/hbm/Aula.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And this is my path:

[Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dkeI.jpg)

Is it a configuration problem? I need some help because I'm new in hibernate and don't know what exactly I'm doing. If there are some errors on my cfg i dont see them.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

From what i see it looks like it is missing hibernate.cfg file or it is not in the correct format. Why don't you take a sample project from internet to understand then structure.

Comment: I post my hibernate.cfg.xml on my main post.